# Curl can't load temporary files from vfs://

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl, lumen

I'm trying to send a file through Curl that was created in vfs:// on Google App Engine.  It works fine but Curl can't for some reason, load the file returning an error "Can't load file from...".  I have double checked with `file_get_contents` function and the file is still there when Curl is called so it's not the case of non existing file.  This problem occurs only in GAE filesystem.

The file is created using `tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'file');`.

Does this problem have something to do with Curl not being properly supported on GAE?
What is the correct way to create temporary files for Curl to read in GAE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curl is not supported on GAE properly so I used [GuzzleHTTP](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) and it solved my issue.